# find out what entity has changed (NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, notifications

i hope someone can help me...

my code look like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(makeSomeThing:) name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
         object:nil];
```

i want to know which entity has changed no matter delete or update. just
which entity...
i want do something like that

```
-(void)makeSomeThing: (NSNotification *)noti
{
    if(entity == CarEntity)
        NSLog(@"makeSomeThing");
}
```

i can not figure out what entity has changed... i know there is a method `[noti userInfo]` but
i dont know what to do whit this.

thx and sorry for this horrible englich :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NSDictionary returned by `[noti userInfo]` for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` may contain keys NSInsertedObjectsKey, NSUpdatedObjectsKey, and NSDeletedObjectsKey. So `[[noti userInfo] objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey]` will give you the objects inserted; the other two keys work similarly.

Do note that multiple objects can be inserted, updated, and/or deleted in one notification.

Comment: @user656219: Note that when an answer resolves your problem, you should mark it "accepted" by clicking the check box outline to the left of the answer.